# sqlalchemy create_engine function not working while running file name testalchemy.py

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy create_engine function  not working while running from file but it work fine in python shell so cannot found the issue. So please anybody point out the issue. I am user window 10 and python version 3.5.3.

Here is the error while running script file:

```
C:\python\python.exe C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Auto/pythonseltest/Tests/sqlalchemy.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Auto/pythonseltest/Tests/sqlalchemy.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine   File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Auto\pythonseltest\Tests\sqlalchemy.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine ImportError: cannot import name 'create_engine'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

here is the actual code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine =create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://username:password@localhost:3306/databasename')
connection = engine.connect() result = connection.execute('select *
from cuser')
```

this code work fine if i type this code line by line in python shell but while try to run the file it shows above error.

Comment: Looks like some versions of sqlalchemy require `from sqlalchemy.orm import create_engine`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because your have a file on your working directory named sqlalchemy.py. Following the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), when importing a module, python looks in CWD before trying the directories from the $PYTHONPATH. And I guess your have no `create_engine` in `C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Auto/pythonseltest/Tests/sqlalchemy.py`.

Comment: Thx. I ran into the exact same problem. My file-to-play-with had the same name. Stoopid me.

Comment: Thanks. I made the same mistakes. Always try to avoid to use a module names in use as a file name.