# How does importing a library work in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, sqlalchemy

When I run this code, I assume it's importing everything from that library:

```
import sqlalchemy
```

When I try to use `create_engine`, it tells me that

> create_engine is not defined.

When I run this code, I assume it's only importing the `create_engine` class

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

it works without a problem.

Why does the 2nd piece of code work but not the first when I try to use `create_engine`?

I saw [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), but I need someone to dumb it down for me.

Comment: This may be of help: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: `import sqlalchemy` is the package. You then call each method as such `sqlalchemy.create_engine `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlalchemy create\_engine function not working while running file name testalchemy.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389724/sqlalchemy-create-engine-function-not-working-while-running-file-name-testalchem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like:

```
import sqlalchemy
```

You're not actually importing anything, that is why the module is not found. Sure the syntax is correct hence the IDE is not gonna give you errors. If you want to import everything from a library you use:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
```

This is not good practice though. That is why you specify your imports always.

Comment: This answers my question, but as a quick follow up, why do people specify from with sqlalchemy, but not with other libraries like pandas, os, or re?

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles this is slightly misleading. You ARE `import`ing the `sqlalchemy` module. But when you use `import sqlalchemy` you need to specify everything you use with dot syntax `sqlalchemy.create_engine`. That's why people mostly use `as` to to shorten the module name. `import sqlalchemy as sa` and then `sa.create_engine`. When you use `from sqlalchemy import *` you bring in everything in the `sqlalchemy` module into your namespace `create_engine`, etc.. It's bad practice because it pollutes your namespace and its not obvious at a glance where a function or class came from.

Comment: Exactly this, i tried to keep it simple, thank you for adding to the answer.